# $ n $-Cats-in-a-Bed Problem: Picking $ n $ points in a given planar domain to maximize the sum of their pairwise distances

Tags: plane-geometry

Let $ C $ be a connected and simply connected compact subset of the plane $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $. How can we pick $ n $ points, denoted $ x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} $, lying in $ C $ such that the total sum $ \displaystyle D \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \sum_{i,j = 1}^{n} d(x_{i},x_{j}) $ of their pairwise distances is maximized? For example, $ C $ could be the region consisting of a simple closed curve and its interior.

Comment: The question is unclear: how is the domain given in the input? How efficient you want your algorithm be (exact? approximate in some sense?). Also, what do you already know?

Comment: I don't think your question is easily answered. Here's an old paper on the topic: "On the sum of distances determined by a pointset"; *Acta Mathematica Academiae Scientiarum Hungarica*, Volume 7, Issue 3-4, pp 397-401. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02020534))

Comment: When $n=1$, the solution can be found at http://www.sleepingcatsw.com/images/cats/luther_bed.jpg

Comment: In the case n=2, a Google image search indicates that pairs of cats in a bed tend not to maximize their pairwise distance.  This may be a case of sampling bias however.

Comment: I love the title which suggests an obvious near-solution: put $n$ unfriendly cats in room of shape $C$.